# My Ubuntu 14.04 LTS doesn't have sound

Tags: ubuntu, audio, vmware

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on VMware workstation version 10.0.0 on my Windows 7 machine. After installing I figured out that it doesn't have any sound so I checked the sound settings. All items seem to be at their default states and correct. Any suggestion to find the problem?

Comment: Do you install the vmware tools  on your vm ?

Answer (score 0):

If `lspci|grep snd_ens1371` gives some output the sound kernel modules are loaded & sound is probably muted in `alsamixer`. Muted channels show up as 'MM' & can be **unmuted** by selecting them & pressing **M**.

If alsamixer does not detect a sound card run:

```
alsactl init
```

If you are using `pulseaudio` check `/etc/asound.conf`contains a minimum of:

```
pcm.pulse { type pulse }
ctl.pulse { type pulse }
pcm.!default { type pulse }
ctl.!default { type pulse }
```

I also changed the sound device settings in VMWARE to my detected speakers (from default host device).

Reboot & sound will work.

This fixed `xfce4-volume-control` / `gstreamer` complaining no sound card can be found & warning of a possible permissions problem. Trying to run just ALSA under Debian Wheezy 64 bit in VMWARE still gave this gstreamer error. VMWARE seems to run a little better with pulseaudio also being installed (sound in Virtualbox ran just fine with only ALSA).

Answer (score 0):

Following command should resolve your issue:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

If that won't help you, try to reinstall ALSA and pulseaudio with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```